# Using an ADODB record set to perform a joined update query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In the following code, I would like to join ADODB record set 'rs3' to table 'tblValueChain10' and update 3 different columns based on the values extracted in the ADODB record set 'rs3'.   Currently, the update query is not returning anything.

```
Dim st_Sql3 As String
Dim rs3 As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs3 = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Max3 As Integer

rs3.Open "SELECT tblRisk05Holding.IDMacroProcesso01, tblRisk05Holding.Level01Risk, Max(tblRisk05Holding.ManualityStatus) AS MaxDiManualityStatus, Max(tblRisk05Holding.RiskProbabilityStatus) AS MaxDiRiskProbabilityStatus, Max(tblRisk05Holding.RiskExposureStatus) AS MaxDiRiskExposureStatus FROM tblRisk05Holding GROUP BY tblRisk05Holding.IDMacroProcesso01, tblRisk05Holding.Level01Risk", CurrentProject.Connection


st_Sql3 = "UPDATE tblValueChain10 INNER JOIN rs3 ON (tblValueChain10.IDMacroProcesso01 = tblRisk05Holding.IDMacroProcesso01) SET L1RiskManuality = " & rs3.Fields(2) & ", L1RiskProbability = " & rs3.Fields(3) & ", L1RiskGravity = " & rs3.Fields(4) & ""
Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_Sql2)

rs3.Close
Set rs3 = Nothing
```

Comment: While this is not the same as an answer, I'd like explain that in my experience this kind of situation is best solved by using a `Do...Loop` structure to process each line of the recordset. It is lazy, compared with pure SQL, but it allows control and makes trouble shooting much easier.

Answer (score 6):

Access never allows you to use a recordset object as a data source in another query.  It doesn't matter whether you have an ADO or DAO recordset; you can't do it.  And the query type (`SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, etc.) also doesn't matter; you can't use a recordset object as a data source in any query type.

You might get a workable `UPDATE` by first saving your `SELECT` statement as a named query, *qryRS3*.  Then revise the `UPDATE` to `INNER JOIN` *tblValueChain10* to *qryRS3*.  But I'm uncertain whether Access would consider that query to be updatable; the `GROUP BY` might cause Access to treat it as not updatable.  You'll have to test to see.

Answer (score 3):

Although the goal you try to achieve using ADO Recordset in the way presented can't be done (as user @HansUp wrote), you could try the approach with updating your table `tblValueChain10` using subquery taken from the `rs3` recordset open call.

I hope that the following query :

```
UPDATE 
  tblValueChain10 
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT 
       tblRisk05Holding.IDMacroProcesso01, 
       tblRisk05Holding.Level01Risk, 
       Max(tblRisk05Holding.ManualityStatus) AS MaxDiManualityStatus, 
       Max(tblRisk05Holding.RiskProbabilityStatus) AS MaxDiRiskProbabilityStatus, 
       Max(tblRisk05Holding.RiskExposureStatus) AS MaxDiRiskExposureStatus 
    FROM 
       tblRisk05Holding 
    GROUP BY 
       tblRisk05Holding.IDMacroProcesso01, 
       tblRisk05Holding.Level01Risk
  ) AS qry_Risk05Holding
  ON (tblValueChain10.IDMacroProcesso01 = qry_Risk05Holding.IDMacroProcesso01) 
SET 
  tblValueChain10.L1RiskManuality = qry_Risk05Holding.MaxDiManualityStatus, 
  tblValueChain10.L1RiskProbability = qry_Risk05Holding.MaxDiRiskProbabilityStatus, 
  tblValueChain10.L1RiskGravity = qry_Risk05Holding.MaxDiRiskExposureStatus
```

could help you solve your problem.

**You should be able to run the above SQL with the following code:**

```
Dim st_Sql3 As String

st_Sql3 = " UPDATE tblValueChain10 INNER JOIN ( "

st_Sql3 = st_Sql3 & " SELECT  " _
    & " tblRisk05Holding.IDMacroProcesso01,  " _
    & " tblRisk05Holding.Level01Risk,  " _
    & " Max(tblRisk05Holding.ManualityStatus) AS MaxDiManualityStatus,  " _
    & " Max(tblRisk05Holding.RiskProbabilityStatus) AS MaxDiRiskProbabilityStatus,  " _
    & " Max(tblRisk05Holding.RiskExposureStatus) AS MaxDiRiskExposureStatus  "

st_Sql3 = st_Sql3 & " FROM  " _
    & " tblRisk05Holding  " _
    & " GROUP BY  " _
    & " tblRisk05Holding.IDMacroProcesso01,  " _
    & " tblRisk05Holding.Level01Risk "

st_Sql3 = st_Sql3 & " ) AS qry_Risk05Holding " _
  & " ON (tblValueChain10.IDMacroProcesso01 = qry_Risk05Holding.IDMacroProcesso01) " _
  & " SET " _
  & " tblValueChain10.L1RiskManuality = qry_Risk05Holding.MaxDiManualityStatus,  " _
  & " tblValueChain10.L1RiskProbability = qry_Risk05Holding.MaxDiRiskProbabilityStatus, " _
  & " tblValueChain10.L1RiskGravity = qry_Risk05Holding.MaxDiRiskExposureStatus "

Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_Sql3)
```

The query is being built-up in four stages because as far as I remember there is a restriction in VBA that there can't be too many line breaks `_`.

Please notice also that the `JOIN` used in the update query assumes that connecting two tables by `IDMacroProcesso01` would ensure that the records are updated in the right way.

I can't check the solution in Acces right now but maybe it could somehow help you, at least a concept. If there were any errors, please write.

Comment: I'm not sure why he's not creating a new query with the sql you posted above instead of building the sql at runtime.

Comment: @Beth thx for your comment. Good point. I didn't thought about it but could be a good option to consider for question author. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through the recordset to iteratively update by each record:

```
Do While NOT rs3.EOF

       st_Sql3 = "UPDATE tblValueChain10"_
                 & " INNER JOIN rs3 ON (tblValueChain10.IDMacroProcesso01 = tblRisk05Holding.IDMacroProcesso01)" _
                 & " SET L1RiskManuality = " & rs3.Fields(2) & ", L1RiskProbability = " & rs3.Fields(3) & "," _
                 & " L1RiskGravity = " & rs3.Fields(4) & "" 
       DoCmd.RunSQL (st_Sql3)

rs3.MoveNext
Loop
```

Also please note, your RunSQL () command is calling the incorrect SQL string.

Answer (score 2):

If no err appears, then try to place this code:

```
Set rs3 = New ADODB.Recordset
```

in **form_load**, as in,

```
private sub Form_load()
Set rs3 = New ADODB.Recordset
End Sub
```

**note**: this sample is in vb6.0. that's what I can do. Besides, check the version in references